# Page-Range-Problem at Printing a Document

Tags: c#, printing, printdialog

i try to print out the content of my editor:

```
PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();

pd.PageRangeSelection = PageRangeSelection.AllPages;
pd.UserPageRangeEnabled = true;

FlowDocument fd = DocumentPrinter.CreateFlowDocumentForEditor(CurrentDocument.Editor);
DocumentPaginator dp = ((IDocumentPaginatorSource)fd).DocumentPaginator;

bool? res = pd.ShowDialog();

if (res.HasValue && res.Value)
{
    fd.PageHeight = pd.PrintableAreaHeight;
    fd.PageWidth = pd.PrintableAreaWidth;
    fd.PagePadding = new Thickness(50);
    fd.ColumnGap = 0;
    fd.ColumnWidth = pd.PrintableAreaWidth;

    pd.PrintDocument(dp, CurrentDocument.Editor.FileName);
}
```

The test-document i used has about 14 pages (with this pagesize-settings). 
i tested it: the printdialog appears and I´ve chosen a pagerange (i typed "1-3" into the textbox) and clicked `print`. above the `printdocument()` I set a breakpoint and looked into the printdialog-object. it says `pd.PageRangeSelection = PageRangeSelection.UserPage` and `pd.PageRange = {1-3}`. I guess this is right, because I wanted to print out only page 1-3. then the `printdocument()` executed and in the output-pdf (for testing I use a pdf-printer) has 14 pages (the whole document was printed).

where is my mistake? why does the pagerange-setting not work?

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

In your code you manually set:

```
pd.PageRangeSelection = PageRangeSelection.AllPages;
```

This is why your code prints all the pages.

Comment: this is not the reason. i already said that i have debugged it and the PageRangeSelection-Property is set to UserPages before the PrintDocument()-Method is executed

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is because `FlowDocument`'s `DocumentPaginator` does not handle `UserPageRange`s. You can see that [`FlowDocument`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/Documents/FlowDocument.cs,1708) implementation creates a [`FlowDocumentPaginator`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/MS/Internal/Documents/FlowDocumentPaginator.cs,cb18d40cc5615fc7), and it doesn't take into account ranges.

If it did handle it, in [`FlowDocumentPaginator.(Async)GetPage`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/MS/Internal/Documents/FlowDocumentPaginator.cs,144) you would see, code checking to see if the page requested to be printed is in an index of available pages; or maybe if a key exists in a `Dictionary` whose value is the `DocumentPage` to print.

In other words, and the reason the `PrintDialog` default has `UserPageRangeEnabled` set to `false`, is because in order to use that feature, you'll usually have to write your own `DocumentPaginator` or you have to add some logic to compile a new temporary document to hold only the pages you want to print.

Feel free to ask any questions.